# Vernacular differences between São Paulo and Rio de Janeiro?

Tags: regionalismo

In the early 90s, I was dating a Paulista in Houston and I had a Portuguese tutor from Rio.  One day she put on a video of a comedy segment from Brazilian TV for a group of Brazilians.  Someone was having fun with the vernacular differences between Rio and São Paulo.  It was all over my head at the time (and still is!), but I remember they were all in stitches.  The only item I remember was that they say "upside down" or "stand on your head" differently, but I have no idea of the actual Portuguese.

Would anyone know this comedy segment, or another place I might learn more about these regional differences?  I figure it would be on YouTube by now, if I knew where to look.

Comment: Do you say *de ponta-cabeça* instead of *de cabeça para baixo*?

Comment: The accent is what is the most different.

Comment: do you have the link for the video? it is kind of hard to understand what kind of difference you are talking about...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can understand spoken Portuguese, I suggest you to watch Portuguese With Leo on you YouTube, specifically videos where he talks to Brazilians like Márcia Macedo, who is Paulista.

I am from Belém do Pará and my accent is different from Paulista one and is a little bit similar to Carioca. For example in "xadrez" (chess), I pronounce "z" just like the "x", sounding like a "sh" in "smash" but a little bit longer.

Some paraenses say "eu *tava* em casa" (I was at home) pronuncing "v" just like the "j" in Spanish (for example, in Javier")

Comment: Ok, I have now removed my comment

Comment: Hello, Marcos, welcome to the site! I believe Lester was asking about differences in vocabulary, not in pronunciation — as that we say *mistura* in São Paulo for a part of the dish, but not all Cariocas do. Thank you for the answer either way!

Comment: You're right... By the way Lester said a word which I haven't heard before... Vernacular. Neither in Portuguese! Always learning even in my mother language :})